# Using strpos to matching â€¦ and

Tags: php, utf

I have this `â€¦` symbol showing up on my page instead of `...` and I tried to use both to see if it's in the string using:

```
echo $matches[$indexN];
if (strpos($matches[$indexN], "â€¦") === false && strpos($matches[$indexN], "...") === false) {
echo "false";
}
```

**The output of $matches[$indexN]:**

```
â€¦
```

**The output of the if statement:**

```
false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the site available publicly?

Comment: I think `â€` is a two character representation of a multibyte character. What was the input? Maybe try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php.. Is everything utf8?

Comment: @chris85 I used file_get_contents to get the contents from this site: view-source:http://notalwaysright.com/page/4

Comment: Where is the `â€` part at? Your PHP is utf8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

â€¦ is the ANSI interpretation of an ellipsis (…) encoded in UTF-8. An ellipsis is one character, whereas it looks like you are passing three (three periods) to `strpos`. Incidentally, when working with a multibyte encoding such as UTF-8, you'll need to use `mb_strpos` instead.